# how to render an element for every selected element inside multi selectbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Right now I render for every selected element inside my multiselect angular material selectbox.

The rendering works when I am selecting an element inside it. But when I deselect one it does just keeps adding.

My guess is that I have to set a property like deselect or something but I am not sure, could someone help me out?

HTML:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="person" required>
    <mat-option>--</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let person of person" [value]="person" (click)="getPerson()">
      {{person.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>

<div *ngFor="let person of personsArray">
    <div class="card"  >
        <div class="card-body dl-card-body-no-padding-bottom" >  
            //element to render
    </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
getPerson(){
   this.personsArray.push(this.form.controls.person.value)
}
```

Comment: Could you add a minimal reproduction in Stackblitz or CodeSandbox?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML for your `mat-select` you will need to include the `multiple` attribute.

Also, make sure you appropriately name the arrays to store the items from the source array and the selected array. It's rather confusing to refer to `person` twice in the select template.

You need to pass data into the selection handler. This is done as shown in the amended HTML below:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="person" required multiple>
  <mat-option>--</mat-option>
  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let person of personsArray"
    [value]="person"
    (click)="getPerson(person)"
  >
    {{ person.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

In your component code, include an array for the source array and selected items array:

```
form: any;
person = new FormControl('');
personsArray: Person[] = [
    { name: 'bob' },
    { name: 'dave' },
    { name: 'fred' },
];
selectedPersonsArray: Person[] = [];

constructor() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      person: new FormControl(''),
    });
}
```

In your selection handler, you need to handle the appending and removal of items depending on whether they already exist (remove) or do not exist (append) in the select items array:

```
getPerson(val: Person) {
  console.log('selected person = ' + val.name);
  const person: Person = this.selectedPersonsArray.find(
    (p) => p.name === val.name
  );
  console.log('sel person=' + person?.name);
  if (!person) this.selectedPersonsArray.push(val);
  if (person?.name)
    this.selectedPersonsArray = this.selectedPersonsArray.filter(
      (p) => p.name !== val.name
    );
}
```

The person object is just an interface similar to this:

```
export interface Person {
    name: string;
}
```

The above is sufficient to allow selected or un-selected items within multi-selection drop down to display within the rendered list.

Comment: I will try this tonight sorry for the late reply had to work on something else